# Dependent drop down lists in Excel going three ways

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu

I have three columns in Excel: column A is first name, column B is last name, column C is nationality. In column D there are three drop down lists. D1 is a dropdown list that has all the first names in it, D2 is a dropdown list that has all the last names in it, D3 is a dropdown list that has the nationality in it.

What I am trying to do is the following:
Let's say I type a first name into box D1, then I want the drop down lists in D2 and D3 to change to only values that would be possible with that first name based on the list of data (e.g. if I type in the name Carl, then only last names and nationalities that existing Carl's in my data belong to would show up in the other drop down boxes)

The same thing would happen if I type in a last name into D2, then the dropdown lists in D1 and D3 would change to only values that correspond to that last name.

Finally, if I choose a nationality in D3, it would only bring up first and last names that belong to that nationality. If I were then to choose a first name, it would only bring up last names that belong to both that first name and nationality.

Is this possible in Excel without using any VBA or macros? I know how to do it for one-way dependency (http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html); however, not sure how to do it for two or three way dependency as I described above.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the function you are looking for is called `indirect()`. example how to use it:

1. assume `A1 = "A"`, `A2 = "B"`, `A3 = "C"`
2. select `range(A1:A3)`
3. go to `"formulas"` - `"name manager"` - `"new"` - give a name eg `"myrange"`
4. navigate to cell `B1` - go to `"data"` - `"data validation"` - in tab `"setting"` select under `allow` - `"list"` - in `source` (bellow) type - `=INDIRECT("myrange")`

then you can choose in cell `B1` - `A`, `B` or `C`. 
If you work in this direction further, you will be able to answer your question. Have a look for example [here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kYzmBncec4).

good luck